# Build Duplicate matching rule for long text fields using a custom hashCode

Tags: hashcode, duplicate-management

To find duplicates of a custom object I planned using Salesforce.com's **native Duplicate Management** functionality. I was a bit disappointed to see that matching rules are not able to compare **Long text field**.

In my case `CustomObject__c` X and Y are equal if all of its 50 long text attributte fields are equal.

I thought of this workaround but am a bit afraid that this is a bit hacky, has bad performance and other drawbacks:

1. Add a `txt_Hashcode__c` field to `CustomObject__c`
2. Add **BeforeInsert** and **BeforeUpdate** trigger that [uses the Apex Crypto class to create a hashcode](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class) out of the 50 long text fields and populate the field
3. Add Duplicate rule that only checks for equality of this field.

What do you think?

Comment: Any reason you chose to use the `after` trigger rather than a `before` trigger?  BTW, we've done something similar, but not for 50 long text fields! :)

Comment: You are right a BEFORE trigger is better. I changed it. Can you elaborate more on a) what and how you did it and b) if you see any risks in doing it for 50 long text fields?